# Redux Toolkit Query not fetching data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, next.js

I am trying to fetch data with RTK Query in next.js project and everything were fine until I had to fetch some more data from /api/exams endpoint. I have fetched almost everything from that endpoint and i know that's working fine but i still can't fetch some data from it. I'll provide screenshots of all code that's related to it. ok so here is the code where endpoints are: [image]

Then let's continue with exams-response where i define body of endpoint: [image]

Now I will provide code in my custom hook where i import that data from api/exams endpoint query: [image]

And now i will show code of the actual page where i use them and where i think problem may lie also with another file which i will provide after this:

```
import { memo } from "react"
import { useIntl } from "react-intl"
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"

import { ExamoTypesEnum } from "src/common/types/examo-types-enum"
import { rolesEnum } from "src/core/roles-enum"
import { useExamAssign } from "src/features/exams/hooks/use-exam-assign"
import { useExams } from "src/features/exams/hooks/use-exams"
import { useStartExam } from "src/features/exams/hooks/use-start-exam"
import { useIsMobile } from "src/helpers/use-is-mobile"
import { useAppSelector } from "src/redux/hooks"
import { ExamoCard } from "src/ui/examo/examo-card"
import { ExamoCardsGrid } from "src/ui/examo/examo-cards-grid"
import { ExamoHeader } from "src/ui/examo/examo-header"
import { CustomizedDialogs } from "src/ui/filter"
import { LoadingSpinner } from "src/ui/loading-spinner"
import { styled } from "src/ui/theme"
import { UnauthenticatedComponent } from "src/ui/unauthenticated"

import { useTags } from "../tags/hooks/use-tags"
import { useActiveExamQuery } from "./api"

const Ourbox = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
`

export const ExamsPage = memo(() => {
  const isMobile = useIsMobile()
  const userRole = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth.role)
  const intl = useIntl()

  const {
    exams,
    isLoadingExams,
    selectedTags,
    setSelectedTags,
    checkedFilterTags,
    setCheckedFilterTags,
  } = useExams()

  const { availableTags } = useTags()
  const isLoadingAnExam = useAppSelector((state) => state.exam.isLoadingAnExam)
  const { startAsync } = useStartExam()

  const { data: activeExam, isFetching: isFetchingActiveExam } =
    useActiveExamQuery(undefined, { refetchOnMountOrArgChange: 1 })

  if (userRole === rolesEnum.None) {
    return <UnauthenticatedComponent />
  }

  return (
    <Stack sx={{ paddingX: isMobile ? 3 : "10vw", paddingY: 4 }} gap={4}>
      <Ourbox>
        <ExamoHeader
          header={intl.formatMessage({
            id: "exams-header",
            defaultMessage: "Choose your exam",
          })}
          subtitle={intl.formatMessage({
            id: "exams-header-subtitle",
            defaultMessage:
              "Our operators make quizzes and tests to help you upgrade and test your skills.",
          })}
        />
        <CustomizedDialogs
          id="exams-page-filter"
          selectedTags={selectedTags}
          setSelectedTags={setSelectedTags}
          availableTags={availableTags || []}
          checkedFilterTags={checkedFilterTags}
          setCheckedFilterTags={setCheckedFilterTags}
        />
      </Ourbox>
      {isLoadingExams && <LoadingSpinner />}
      {!isLoadingExams && (!exams || exams.length === 0) && (
        <Typography>
          {intl.formatMessage({
            id: "no-exams-available",
            defaultMessage: "No exams available",
          })}
        </Typography>
      )}
      {exams && exams.length > 0 && (
        <ExamoCardsGrid>
          {exams.map((exam) => (
            <ExamoCard
              key={exam.id}
              type={ExamoTypesEnum.EXAM}
              useAssign={useExamAssign}
              isStartButtonDisabled={
                isLoadingAnExam ||
                isFetchingActiveExam ||
                (activeExam?.exam?.id !== undefined &&
                  exam.id !== activeExam.exam.id)
              }
              isResuming={
                activeExam?.exam?.id !== undefined &&
                exam.id === activeExam.exam.id
              }
              handleStart={() => startAsync(exam.id)}
              isLoading={isLoadingAnExam}
              title={exam.title}
              duration={exam.duration}
              tags={[
                ...new Set(exam.templates?.flatMap((et) => et.tags) || []),
              ]}
              numberOfQuestions={exam.templates.reduce(
                (total, current) => total + current.numberOfQuestions,
                0,
              )}
              deadline-start={exam["deadline-start"]}
              deadline-end={exam["deadline-end"]}
              i={exam.id}
            />
          ))}
        </ExamoCardsGrid>
      )}
    </Stack>
  )
})
```

and the last one which is  as mapped through in above the code. so it's :

```
import { memo } from "react"
import * as React from "react"
import { useIntl } from "react-intl"
import AccessTimeIcon from "@mui/icons-material/AccessTime"
import ExpandMoreIcon from "@mui/icons-material/ExpandMore"
import MoreHorizIcon from "@mui/icons-material/MoreHoriz"
import Box from "@mui/material/Box"
import Card from "@mui/material/Card"
import MuiChip from "@mui/material/Chip"
import Collapse from "@mui/material/Collapse"
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid"
import IconButton, { IconButtonProps } from "@mui/material/IconButton"
import Stack from "@mui/material/Stack"
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles"
import Typography from "@mui/material/Typography"

import { ExamoTypesEnum } from "src/common/types/examo-types-enum"
import { useAssignType } from "src/common/types/use-assign-type"
import { useAppSelector } from "src/redux/hooks"
import { ExamoAssignTo } from "src/ui/examo/examo-assign-to"
import { ExamoStartDialogBtn } from "src/ui/examo/examo-start-btn"
interface props {
  duration: string | null
  title: string
  tags: string[] | null
  numberOfQuestions: number | null
  isLoading: boolean
  handleStart: () => void
  useAssign: useAssignType
  isStartButtonDisabled: boolean
  isResuming: boolean
  type: ExamoTypesEnum
  i: number
  "deadline-start": string
  "deadline-end": string
}
export const ExamoCard = memo(
  ({
    duration,
    tags,
    title,
    isLoading,
    numberOfQuestions,
    isStartButtonDisabled,
    isResuming,
    type,
    handleStart,
    useAssign,
    i,
    "deadline-end": deadlineEnd,
    "deadline-start": deadlineStart,
  }: props) => {
    console.log(deadlineStart)

    const intl = useIntl()
    const user = useAppSelector((state) => state.auth)
    const durationHours = duration?.split(":")[0]
    const durationMinutes = duration?.split(":")[1]
    // const [expanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false)
    const [expandedId, setExpandedId] = React.useState(-1)

    // const handleExpandClick = () => {
    //   setExpanded(!expanded)
    // }
    const handleExpandClick = (i: number) => {
      setExpandedId(expandedId === i ? -1 : i)
    }

    const preventParentOnClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLElement>) => {
      event.stopPropagation()
    }

    interface ExpandMoreProps extends IconButtonProps {
      expand: boolean
    }

    const ExpandMore = styled((props: ExpandMoreProps) => {
      const { expand, ...other } = props

      return <IconButton {...other} />
    })(({ theme, expand }) => ({
      transform: !expand ? "rotate(0deg)" : "rotate(180deg)",
      transition: theme.transitions.create("transform", {
        duration: theme.transitions.duration.shortest,
      }),
    }))

    return (
      <Grid item xs={12} lg={6}>
        <Card
          onClick={() => handleExpandClick(i)}
          aria-expanded={expandedId === i}
          elevation={2}
          sx={{
            padding: "1rem",
            height: "100%",
            borderRadius: "1rem",
            border: "solid 1px var(--palette-grey-400)",
            transition: "all 0.1s ease-in-out",
            ":hover": {
              backgroundColor: "var(--palette-grey-100)",
              cursor: "pointer",
            },
          }}
        >
          <Stack direction="row" justifyContent="space-between">
            <Stack
              gap={numberOfQuestions ? 1.5 : 6}
              sx={{
                width: "100%",
              }}
            >
              <Stack
                direction="row"
                sx={{
                  justifyContent: "space-between",
                }}
              >
                <Typography
                  variant="h5"
                  sx={{ whiteSpace: "pre-wrap", wordBreak: "break-all" }}
                >
                  {title}
                </Typography>
                <ExpandMore expand={expandedId === i}>
                  <ExpandMoreIcon />
                </ExpandMore>
                <Stack
                  direction="row"
                  gap={1}
                  sx={{
                    justifyContent: "flex-end",
                    alignItems: "center",
                    marginTop: "-1.75rem",
                  }}
                >
                  <AccessTimeIcon />
                  <Typography
                    whiteSpace="nowrap"
                    variant="h6"
                  >{`${durationHours}h ${durationMinutes}m`}</Typography>
                </Stack>
              </Stack>
              <Collapse in={expandedId === i} timeout="auto" unmountOnExit>
                <Stack direction="row" gap={4}>
                  {numberOfQuestions && (
                    <Typography variant="h6">
                      {`${numberOfQuestions}  ${intl.formatMessage({
                        id: "questions",
                        defaultMessage: "Questions",
                      })}`}
                    </Typography>
                  )}
                </Stack>
                <Stack
                  direction="row"
                  sx={{ flexWrap: "wrap", gap: 1, marginTop: "1rem" }}
                >
                  {tags?.map((t, index) => (
                    <MuiChip
                      key={index}
                      label={t}
                      variant="filled"
                      sx={{ fontWeight: "bold" }}
                      color="secondary"
                      size="small"
                    />
                  ))}
                </Stack>
              </Collapse>
            </Stack>
            <Stack
              sx={{ marginTop: "-0.5rem" }}
              justifyContent="space-between"
              alignItems="center"
              spacing={user.role === "Operator" ? 0.1 : 1}
            >
              <MoreHorizIcon sx={{ marginLeft: "2rem" }} />
              <Box onClick={preventParentOnClick}>
                <Stack sx={{ marginLeft: "1.5rem" }}>
                  {user.role === "Operator" && (
                    <ExamoAssignTo useAssign={useAssign} title={title} />
                  )}
                </Stack>
              </Box>
              <Box onClick={preventParentOnClick}>
                <ExamoStartDialogBtn
                  type={type}
                  isResuming={isResuming}
                  handleStart={handleStart}
                  isLoading={isLoading}
                  isDisabled={isStartButtonDisabled}
                />
              </Box>
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        </Card>
      </Grid>
    )
  },
```

)

To sum up guys, I want to also fetch deadlineStart and deadlineEnd but i can't. I think problem is in last file or second to last, because maybe am not defining them properly in interface props in last code. And also i almost forgot to mention that when I try to console.log(deadlineStart) in the last code it says undefined in the browser.  Edited Network Pic : [image]

here is screenshot when i console log single exams : [image]

Comment: Can you simplify the example code please which shows the problematic code part only. If the example is full of unrelated imports and UI elems it is much harder to find someone who helps you.

Comment: @gazdagergo I have posted same question with small information and someone disliked the post and said I hadn't enough information and that's why I provided everything now. Ok so problem lies in last two files of codes I have provided. The first 3 screenshots don't have problem in it i believe.

Comment: Do you have a screenshot of the network tab please with the exams request's details?

Comment: I have added screenshot of network.

Comment: Interfaces do not guarantee that any data will actually be there, that's just a check in your editor that doesn't exist later when data actually arrives from the server. If you `console.log` a single exam, is that data there and what does it look like?

Comment: I have edited my post and added screenshot of console.log a single exam.